# square root using Babylonian method returns wrong value?

Tags: c, struct

> For the function `isqroot()` to calculate the square root using Babylonian method with one degree of precision and return it in a struct.

I'm unable to return the value to the struct and when I compile it is returning garbage value.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

struct rootStruct {
    int rootInt;
    int rootFraction;
};

typedef struct rootStruct RootStruct;
RootStruct* isqroot (int n) {
    /*We are using n itself as initial approximation*/
    RootStruct* root=(RootStruct* )malloc(sizeof(RootStruct));
    float x = n;
    float y = 1;
    float e = 0.1; /* e decides the accuracy level*/

    while(x - y > e) {
        x = (x + y)/2;
        y = n/x;
    }
    root->rootInt = (int)x/2;
    root->rootFraction = (int)(x-root->rootInt)*100;
    return root;
}

int main(){
    RootStruct* roo+t=(RootStruct* )malloc(sizeof(RootStruct));
    printf("the sqrt is %d\n%d\n",root->rootInt,root->rootFraction);
    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Did it even compile ? And you didn't even call your function .

Comment: In your design, you allocate a small amount of memory to hold the resulting root. If you allocate memory with `malloc`, you must also `free` it, which is tedious. Unlike arrays, structs can be passed around as values, so you could rewrite this code without pointers and without extra memory management overhead.

Comment: @MOehm, passing a struct, that is greater than some very minimal size results in a number of hidden calls to memcpy() and memory being set aside for the memcpy() calls to use.  That memory cannot be used for anything else.  I.E. it is a very bad practice to pass structs by passing the whole struct.  It is a much better practice to pass a pointer to the struct.

Comment: when calling the system function: `malloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: @user3629249: The struct in question "weighs" two ints, which amounts to the size of a pointer in modern systems. I doubt that it is copied via `memcpy`. Also note that no struct is passed in, but a struct is returned.  Returning a pointer here has further consequences: The pointer must point to static memory or to newly allocated memory. Static memory means that the result is overwritten by subsequent calls; allocated memory means that the calling code must explicitly free it. In my opinion returning a struct here is the better option if you want to kepp the `x = sqrt(8)` semantics.

Answer (score 2):

You never call `isqroot()`... so `root->rootInt` and `root->rootFraction` are never set.

You also have a typo in

```
RootStruct* roo+t=(RootStruct* )malloc(sizeof(RootStruct));
```

it should be

```
RootStruct* root=(RootStruct* )malloc(sizeof(RootStruct));
```

without the `+`. However, this is unnecessary as you allocate memory in `isqroot()` and should probably be replaced by

```
RootStruct* root = isqroot(9);
```

Then don't forget to `free()` the memory at the end of `main()`.

---

Just to note, you also [shouldn't case the result of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1552737).

---

You have also implemented the algorithm incorrectly, it should be

```
RootStruct* isqroot (int n) {
    RootStruct* root=(RootStruct* )malloc(sizeof(RootStruct));

    float y = 1;
    float e = 0.1; /* e decides the accuracy level*/

    while(fabs(n - y*y) > e) {
        y = (y + (n / y)) / 2;
    }

    root->rootInt = (int) y;
    root->rootFraction = (int) (y - root->rootInt) * 100;

    return root;
}
```

where the complete corrected program is then

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct rootStruct {
    int rootInt;
    int rootFraction;
};

typedef struct rootStruct RootStruct;

RootStruct* isqroot (int n) {
    RootStruct* root=(RootStruct* )malloc(sizeof(RootStruct));

    float y = 1;
    float e = 0.1; /* e decides the accuracy level*/

    while(fabs(n - y*y) > e) {
        y = (y + (n / y)) / 2;
    }

    root->rootInt = (int) y;
    root->rootFraction = (int) (y - root->rootInt) * 100;

    return root;
}

int main() {
    RootStruct* root = isqroot(9);
    printf("The sqrt is %d.%d\n", root->rootInt, root->rootFraction);
    return 0;
}
```

The Wikipedia article on [Computing Square Roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) has a very easy to understand section on the [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method).

Comment: Umm ..I don't think it will work.  I don't mean that you are wrong . But why declaraing `root` inside function and also in `main` ?

Comment: @ameyCU Which part? The code in `isqroot()` seems broken to me but I've answered the question about garbage values due to `isqroot()` not being called.

Comment: Its his code that is not going to work even after the changes you told I think . Unnecessary casts and many things .

Comment: @ameyCU Yes I agree, his code doesn't work even after the changes I've made. He has implemented the algorithm incorrectly. I've answered his problem with not being able to return the `struct` and getting garbage values.

Comment: @ameyCU The edit fixes his errors in coding the algorithm.